# Can nginx be configured to run multiple microservices using different languages under a single domain

Tags: nginx, root, alias

I can get nginx aliases and roots to work for static sites - unfortunately I can't seem to get dynamic content to work.

Basically what I have is a suite of micro services.  Some using the PHP Lumen framework and others using java.

This is all well and good, however each one requires it's own subdomin.  And this is not ideal.  I would prefer a single domain and many paths.  I had hoped that using location and root directives would achieve this and it almost works.  Sadly it's downloading the Lumen source instead of running it.

Has anyone succeeded in doing something similar?